# Can't use wrapped fetch component in my .jsx

Tags: reactjs

I have a MainComponentWrapper that is a fetch Get:

```
export default function MainComponentWrapper({ url, children }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
      },
    })
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then(fetchedData => {
        setData(fetchedData)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
          window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
          window.location.replace("/")
      })
  }, [url])
  if (data === undefined) {
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, { data: data })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I was trying to use it in my .jsx component so i could get data that i need by passing an api url, and print it on a table.

```
export default function Machines({data}) {

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Azure machines</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">resource_group</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">location</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.location}</TableCell>
              <MainComponentWrapper url={"/api/machine/one"} >
                {({ tmpData }) => (
                <TableCell key= {row.location + row.name}  log={console.log(data.status)} align="left">
                <LoadingIndicator/>
                  <MachineStatusIcon
                      status_code={tmpData.status_code}
                      status={tmpData.status}
                   />
               </TableCell>
            )}
           </MainComponentWrapper>
          </TableRow>
         ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>

    </div>

  )
}
```

The problem is I can't find a way to use it, I've checked some similar examples but no success.
If i inspect on google chrome and check the network tab i can see that the component is fetching the data, because the data is listed there, but how do i use it to pass as values to my table?

Comment: How are you handling data in your jsx component (AKA how is it received)? You've omitted that piece.

Comment: Updated the question, basically i pass data as parameter and i can fetch it because i pass the url on a Wrapper that i have on my page: `const MachineWrapper = props => {
  const url = "/api/machine"
  return (
    <MainComponentWrapper url={url}>
      <Machines />
    </MainComponentWrapper>
  )
}` but as i want to fetch here directly i don't know how can i access the objects that i get from the mainComponentWrapper, they are there cause i see them on the network tab.

Comment: My first thought is to console.log the data before you return your JSX in Machines and see what's there. If you can update your question with whatever data is that might help. Also data should never be undefined as it is defined within useState. You need to provide a default value for data. const [data, setData] = React.useState(INITIAL_VALUE)

Answer (score 0):

Your MainComponentWrapper is inside where you have 'data' defined. Your wrapper should envelope the entire JSX code which in this case is the table.

```
<MainComponentWrapper url={"/api/machine/one"} >
<TableBody>
      <!-- data is being used here but it didn't exist -->
      {data.map(row => (
        <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
          <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
            <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                 <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
              </StyledButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">{row.location}</TableCell>
            {({ tmpData }) => (
            <TableCell key= {row.location + row.name}  log={console.log(data.status)} align="left">
            <LoadingIndicator/>
              <MachineStatusIcon
                  status_code={tmpData.status_code}
                  status={tmpData.status}
               />
           </TableCell>
        )}

      </TableRow>
     ))}
    </TableBody>
   </MainComponentWrapper>
```